Collection variable doesn't update in Postman
I've got pre-requests with 2 pm.sendRequest. One of them depends on variable from first response.
They work with setTimeout.
//I set Timeout because updateInfoRequest needs to wait and get it from h2hRequest response
setTimeout("updateInfo", 3000)

updateInfoBody = {"orderId":pm.collectionvariables.get("orderId")}

updateInfoRequest = {
there is connection info
body:JSON.stringify(updateInfoBody)
}

pm.sendRequest(h2hRequest, function(error, h2hResponse){
pm.collectionvariables.set(h2hResponse.json().orderId
})

function updateInfo(){
pm.sendRequest(updateInfoRequest, function(error, updateInfoResponse){
})
}

h2hRequest works. It takes orderId.
It doesn't put in orderId variable after the first call. But I see the value in collection variables.
If run it again - orderId is in variable. But it is the last orderId not new.
I use only Request Tab, not flow or anything else.
How to make pre-request get new orderId every time?
clear or unset commands doesn't help.
Local pre-request variable answers ReferenceError.

P.S. Postman for Windows version 10.10.9. Works without internet connection.
I can't update version following company policy

I tried to wait the finish of h2hRequest and set collectionVariables and variables out of pm.sendRequest scope.
Also doesn't help

I am confuse your explaining , can you draw a diagram for h2hRequest and updateInfoRequest  inputs ,outputs with order ID, want to loop or cascade call. It will be easy to get your solution.

Sorry about that
Can't draw for today
Got h2hRequest and updateInfoRequest
updateInfoRequest should have orderId from h2hRequest response
So I run h2hRequest and updateInfoRequest waits due to setTimeout function
h2hRequest gets response with orderId
And insert this id into updateInfoRequest body
Next updateInfoRequest is out of timeout and runs with orderId in the body
First run h2hRequest gets response with FIRST orderId
But FIRST orderId isn't filled in updateInfoRequest body
Second run h2hRequest gets response with SECOND orderId
But orderId is filled with FIRST value

I draw the diagram this overview is correct?, next question: you want to run loop by change order ID with two requests by run collection?

Yes, your diagram is correct. And order ID is different every run.

I answered your question, I hope to address your problem.

Overview
I made two requests with scrips to get/set collection variables.
It will loop call request depend on variables.
All variables handling on Pre request or Post Request (aka tests tab in old version)

Color Codes
Collection Variables : Blue 
Call Order : Red 
Pre Request/Post Response :Circle Blue 
Request : Green 
Start or End : Orange 
Collection Variables



Variable
Initial value
Current value




orderIds
[1001, 1002, 1003]
[1001, 1002, 1003]


orderId
1001
1001


responseOrderId
null
null




orderIds: Array data, will assign orderId
orderId: will call h2hRequest input query
responseOrderId: After call h2hRequest parse orderId of JSON response


Mock Server
Provides two APIs

h2hRequest

URL
GET /h2h/?{orderId}

Response
{
    "orderId": "{Order ID}",
    "name": "Name {Order ID}",
    "description": "Get Order"
}


updateInfoRequest

URL
POST /update-info/

Input Body
{
    "orderId": {Order ID},
    "name": "Name {Order ID}"
}

Response
{
    "orderId": {Order ID},
    "name": "Name {Order ID}",
    "description": "Update Order"
}

mock-server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json()); // To parse JSON bodies

// GET /h2h endpoint
app.get('/h2h', (req, res) => {
    const orderId = req.query.orderId;
    if (orderId === undefined || orderId === null) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'orderId is required' });
    }
    console.log("/h2h" + orderId);
    res.json({
        orderId: orderId,
        name: `Name ${orderId}`,
        description: 'Get Order'
    });
});

// POST /update-info endpoint
app.post('/update-info', (req, res) => {
    const { orderId } = req.body;
    if (orderId === undefined || orderId === null) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'orderId is required' });
    }
    console.log("/update-info" + orderId);
    res.json({
        orderId: orderId,
        name: `Name ${orderId}`,
        description: 'Update Order'
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Install dependency Run Mock Server
npm install express
node mock-server.js

Client Postmen
Import this 1-demo.postman_collection.json by Postman
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "4c3eea37-233b-403d-b6db-b4810d80bc9a",
        "name": "1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "h2hRequest",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const responseJson = pm.response.json();\r",
                            "pm.collectionVariables.set(\"responseOrderId\", responseJson.orderId)\r",
                            "\r",
                            "console.log(\"responseOrderId: \" + pm.collectionVariables.get(\"responseOrderId\"))\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "let orderIds = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get(\"orderIds\"));\r",
                            "pm.collectionVariables.set(\"orderId\", orderIds.shift())\r",
                            "pm.collectionVariables.set(\"orderIds\", JSON.stringify(orderIds));\r",
                            "orderIds = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get(\"orderIds\"));\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (pm.collectionVariables.get(\"orderId\")){\r",
                            "    pm.execution.setNextRequest(\"updateInfoRequest\"); // <- Next Request Name\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(\"End\")\r",
                            "    pm.execution.setNextRequest(null);\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:3000/h2h?orderId={{orderId}}",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "h2h"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "orderId",
                            "value": "{{orderId}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "updateInfoRequest",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "let orderIds = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get(\"orderIds\"));\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (orderIds.length > 0){\r",
                            "    pm.execution.setNextRequest(\"h2hRequest\"); // <- next GET Request Name\r",
                            "} else {\r",
                            "    console.log(\"This is final step\")\r",
                            "    pm.execution.setNextRequest(null);\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\r\n    \"orderId\": {{responseOrderId}},\r\n    \"name\": \"Name {{responseOrderId}}\"\r\n}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:3000/update-info",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "update-info"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "variable": [
        {
            "key": "orderIds",
            "value": "[1001, 1002, 1003]",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "orderId",
            "value": "1001",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "responseOrderId",
            "value": "null"
        }
    ]
}

After Import


Note :  Wait 3000 (3 seconds) not necessary because the h2hRequest response even it takes long processing time. we just take orderId from response JSON.

h2hRequest
GET http://localhost:3000/h2h?orderId={{orderId}}

In h2hRequest, Pre-request
let orderIds = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get("orderIds"));
pm.collectionVariables.set("orderId", orderIds.shift())
pm.collectionVariables.set("orderIds", JSON.stringify(orderIds));
orderIds = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get("orderIds"));

if (pm.collectionVariables.get("orderId")){
    pm.execution.setNextRequest("updateInfoRequest"); // <- Next Request Name
} else {
    console.log("End")
    pm.execution.setNextRequest(null);
}


In h2hRequest, Post-response
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
pm.collectionVariables.set("responseOrderId", responseJson.orderId)

console.log("responseOrderId: " + pm.collectionVariables.get("responseOrderId"))


updateInfoRequest
POST http://localhost:3000/update-info

Input Body with raw JSON option
{
    "orderId": {{responseOrderId}},
    "name": "Name {{responseOrderId}}"
}


In updateInfoRequest, Post-response
let orderIds = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get("orderIds"));

if (orderIds.length > 0){
    pm.execution.setNextRequest("h2hRequest"); // <- next GET Request Name
} else {
    console.log("This is final step")
    pm.execution.setNextRequest(null);
}

Run Collection

Result
h2hRequest called by orderIds's array number items with each different orderId


Update
If you want to re-run the collection
You should reset all collections current value
as red rectangle
orderIds : [1001, 1002, 1003] 
orderId : 1001 
responseOrderId : null 



Your answer is amazing!
Thank you so much.
It works for a couple requests.
Next runs have the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNextRequest')
And I don't get why it happens(

Thanks for your finding a defect in my scripts. I fixed it try again. It was wrong checking in post-response of updateInfoRequest. It should be check the orderIds length instead of orderId. I updated overview picture too.

Sorry to say it doesn't help.
I still have the error with undefined (reading 'setNestRequest')

Did you try again? let me know your finding is addressed or not.

You need import my new collection file and try again. it mean run mock-server first then run collection.

Yes, I tried again.
Postman and laptop were rebooted, simple request and collection run got this error

Did you see the "This is final step" message in console log as I attached last image?

You need to reset all collection values as the update section. I think you missed that step.

Reseted collection values, again "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNextRequest')".
I think maybe it's my virtual machine problem

It may be an Old Postman issue, can you try not VM and latest Postman v11.1.3

For Postman 10.10.9 I found the solution.
`setTimeout for updateInfo
function updateInfo(){
pm.sendRequest({Put all request info in here}, function(error, updateInfoResponse){
})}`
The orderId isn't updated if I declare updateInfoRequest not in timeout sendReques.
setNestRequest doesn't work in my old Postman.
